# Unable to push files to Github

Tags: remix

I can't push my solidity project to github. I specify that I want to push it from remix to Github. I get a 400 bad request error when I push it.
What I did to resolve the error: I activated DGIT, I put my URL address in the git remote, I created a repository, I added the token in remix that I created from github, I added my email and my user, I did init before pushing, I did add remote., but I still have this same error HTTP ERROR: 400 bad request. Do you have any ideas or advice for me? I also specify that I found a subject close to my problem => https://medium.com/remix-ide/securing-you-file-in-remix-how-to-clone-and-push-f1350111aa13 but the subject doesn't say anything about my mistake. Thank you community.[image: image de l'erreur]

Comment: Check the browser console for more details of the error.

Comment: hello ok I will look thank you.